# Multiple If Or And statements

Tags: excel

I am looking to string together a couple of different If(or(and statements together. Basically to segregate the alphabet out into 3 different sections for one of the and requirements. A-G, H-M & N-Z
My first one (shown below) works fine. Gives me the desired result when E4 meets one of the letter requirements specified requirements;

> =IF(OR((AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="A"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="B"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="C"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="D"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="E"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="F"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="G")),"Operations
>   Database 1 A-G","")

I then tried to tag on another if(or(And statement and receive a #value error.

> =IF(OR((AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="A"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="B"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="C"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="D"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="E"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="F"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="G")),"Operations
>   Database 1
>   A-G",""),IF(OR(AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="H"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="I"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="J"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="K"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="L"),AND(B4="Operational",LEFT(E4,1)="M")),"Operations
>   Database 1 H-M",""))

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your original formula can be significantly reduced. Here are two examples.

```
=IF(AND(B4="Operational", CODE(LEFT(E4))>=65, CODE(LEFT(E4))<=71), "Operations Database 1 A-G", "")
=IF(AND(B4="Operational", OR(LEFT(E4)={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"})), "Operations Database 1 A-G", "")
```

These make the above formulas much easier to add your new conditions.

```
=IF(AND(B4="Operational", CODE(LEFT(E4))>=65, CODE(LEFT(E4))<=71), "Operations Database 1 A-G", IF(AND(B4="Operational", CODE(LEFT(E4))>=72, CODE(LEFT(E4))<=77), "Operations Database 1 H-M", ""))
=IF(AND(B4="Operational", OR(LEFT(E4)={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"})), "Operations Database 1 A-G", IF(AND(B4="Operational", OR(LEFT(E4)={"H","I","J","K","L","M"})), "Operations Database 1 H-M", ""))
```

Further consolidation can be achieved with a lookup into static arrays.

```
=IF(B4="Operational", "Operations Database 1 "&INDEX({"A-G","H-M","N-Z"}, MATCH(LEFT(E4), {"A","H","N"})), "")
```